# Read FAT32 Volume ID on OSX

Tags: macos, fat32

Is there a command in OSX for reading the volume id of a mounted FAT32 file system? I know that the Volume ID is stored at offset 67 of the partition. The issue is that I cannot open the device file and run a seek as the device is already mounted. I just get 'permission denied'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible

http://lists.apple.com/archives/filesystem-dev/2012/Feb/msg00010.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to be root. For instance: **`sudo`**`head /dev/disk0s1` works for me, but `head /dev/disk0s1` doesn't.  Then you just need a program to read offset 67.